# SQL - Get data based on months form a dateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

With SQL Server, I have a column with a launch date (`dateTime`). I want to report on everything that is being launched between all of last month (from viewing date) thru all of this month and next month.

So basically a full 3 month period.

What is the best way to write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT
    @StartDate = DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0),
    @EndDate = DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)

-- DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0), -- beginning of this month
-- DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0), -- beginning of last month
-- DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) -- beginning of next month
-- DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0) -- beginning of two months from now

SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    [LaunchDate] >= @StartDate
AND [LaunchDate] < @EndDate
```

This will give you all the results starting from the beginning of the previous month and before the beginning of two months from now (a full 3 month range)

Comment: I just tested this out and it worked great! Thanks for the very fast reply!

WHERE  launchDate >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) AND (launchDate <= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0))

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like `SELECT /*what_you_want*/ from launches WHERE lauchDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 1, '19000101') AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) + 2, '19000101')`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Foo
FROM Bar
WHERE LaunchDate >= DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
AND LaunchDate <= DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: That wouldn't go to the beginning of the month (which sounds like the OP's intent), but would make a rolling 3 month window.

Comment: @MarkBrackett - "report on everything that is being launched between all of last month (_from viewing date_) thru all of this month and next month"  That sounds like a rolling window request to me.